# Deleting objects stored in formData based on attribute other than key

Tags: javascript, form-data

I am storing files into `formData` like such:

```
formData.append("images[]", file)
formData.append("images[]", file_2)
formData.append("images[]", file_3)
```

I know it's possible to delete the files using `formData.delete()`, but in this case, since all of the keys are the same, how do I specifically delete the object where the value is for example, `file_2`?

Comment: try with this form_data.delete(images['2']);

Comment: Ah, didn't seem to work, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function getAll() returns an array containing all values of a specific key.

```
var values = formData.getAll("images[]");
```

Then you can delete a specific value from the array and set the modified array as new value.

```
var index = values.indexOf(file_2); //only necessary if you dont know the index
values.splice(index, 1);
formData.set("images[]", values);
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is the optimal way. But you can get all values using `getAll`. Then filter and append once again. [Demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/vjn7wyL3/1/)

```
const form = new FormData
form.append('names[]', 'Chris')
form.append('names[]', 'Bob')
form.append('names[]', 'John')

console.log(Array.from(form.entries()))

const names = form.getAll('names[]')

form.delete('names[]')

names
    .filter(name => name !== 'Bob')
    .forEach(name => form.append('names[]', name))

console.log(Array.from(form.entries()))
```

Answer (score 0):

/* Add index */

formData.append("images[0]", file)

formData.append("images[1]", file_2)

formData.append("images[2]", file_3)

/* Remove by index */

formData.delete(`images[${index}]`)

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty fine!

```
// just a generic function to help you removing an element at specific position
function removeAt(array, index) {
    try {
        const length = array.length;
        if (index <= 0)
            return array.slice(1);

        if (index >= length - 1)
            return array.slice(0, length - 1);

        return array.slice(0, index).concat(array.slice(index + 1));

    } catch(err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }

    return null;
}

const currentValue = myFormData.getAll('someKey');
myFormData.delete('someKey');
for (const i of removeAt(currentValue, index)) {
    myFormData.append('someKey', i);
}
```